# ASP.NET WEB API 2 as back-end for multi platform application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-web-api, cross-platform, mobile-application

I need to develop system and I want to do this with .Net technologies. Planning to launch ASP.NET MVC5 web, also there will be mobile apps (WP8/Android/iOS).

The key point is that all business logic will be under WEB API solution. Here is how solution looks like so far:

- MYA.API. WEB API project with ASP.NET Identity.
- MYA.Service. Class library with business logic and error/exception handling.
- MYA.Data. Class library with entity framework/Repositories/UnitOfEWork
- MYA.Models. Class library with domain models for entity framework.

Web page(Mvc) and mobile apps(android/wp/iOs) gonna use this WEB API as the main back-end service. For mobile apps JSON data I think will be OK, but what about MVC web and JSON?  The problem is that I really don't like javascript...

I know that web service could be done with WCF but I want to have WEB API simplicity.

Another option could be to host business logic on WCF and from MVC web application call WCF directly. Then WEB API could be as facade layer to WCF service for mobile app case. But this mean that I will need to duplicate WCF and WEB API methods.

Maybe someone,could give me example or advise in system architecture of cross-platform.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can put MVC and WebAPI in the same project. And the you don't have to make javascript calls for Web API functionality. You just call common code when you render your page.

This of course is a very limited approach as if you write a modern web site you will need to toughen up and dive into JavaScript.

jQuery to your help, look at the SPA visual studio example or angularJS to get started.

Either way there is no reason to throw WCF in the mix for this.